# IRM enabled document library backup and restore

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

We have a SharePoint online-based document repository which has IRM enabled on it. One of our tool does the whole site backup however when we try to restore it at a different site, all the document still has IRM enabled and if we try to open it redirects us to the existing site URL from where the backup was taken.

Just wanted to know how people are tackling backup and restore for IRM enabled document library.

The library contains sensitive documents so we cannot disable IRM on the library.

Thanks for the support.